# How to redefine a style .tippy-tooltip in "react-tippy"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use ["react-tippy"](https://github.com/tvkhoa/react-tippy) for my project.
How can I override the styles .tippy-tooltip?
Me need to remove padding inside the tooltip.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue on my own without any extra gestures. In the global style file, I created the class .tippy-tooltip and set it to "padding: 0 !important".

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Tool tip component I created for my use using react tippy and styled components. You can figure out from there how to customize it to your needs:

Tooltip.js

```
import React from 'react';

import 'tippy.js/dist/tippy.css';
import { TooltipText, StyledTippy } from './Tooltip.styled';

const Tooltip = ({ moveDown, moveRight, content, ...props }) => (
  <StyledTippy
    moveDown={moveDown}
    moveRight={moveRight}
    content={
      <TooltipText small bold>
        {content}
      </TooltipText>
    }
    placement="bottom"
    {...props}
  >
    {props.children}
  </StyledTippy>
);

export default Tooltip;
```

Tooltip.styled.js

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Tippy from '@tippyjs/react';

export const TooltipText = styled.p`
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 12px;
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.tooltips.simpleText};
`;

export const StyledTippy = styled(Tippy)`
  z-index: 5000;
  margin-top: ${({ moveDown }) => (moveDown ? `${moveDown}px` : '0')};
  margin-left: ${({ moveRight }) => (moveRight ? `${moveRight}px` : '0')};
  background: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.tooltips.simpleBackground};
  height: 24px;
  width: 110px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  .tippy-arrow {
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.tooltips.simpleBackground};
  }
`;
```